# Запуск процесса в определенное время c#

Tags: c#

Добрый день!
У меня есть текст бокс , в который я ввожу время часы:минуты:секунды. когда наступает это время ,нужно,чтобы  процесс запускался. Как это можно сделать? 
Куда вписать время запуска?